# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В теме **Алфавит** я написала: "Почему   буквы "ерь" и "ер"  по реформе 1918 года получили неуклюжие названия "мягкий знак" и "твёрдый знак," - и задумалась:   а можно ли так сказать: **получили по реформе**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стилистически этот вариант неудачен. 
Можно сказать "по указу", "по распоряжению", но реформа - это не только жиректива, это еще и процесс... Поэтому лучше "в соответствии с реформой", "в рамках реформы" и т.д.
А в рассматриваемой фразе еще и некоторая двусмысленность просматривается. Типа "получили по шапке". Была у еров реформа, по ней они и получили.

Comment: Спасибо. Я полностью согласна.